# Replacing comma on specific lines only

Tags: text, csv, replace

I have a dataset that is comma separated. But I have a little problem with its format. I want everything to be in the form x,x,x

Below is a sample of my dataset:

```
995970,16779453
995971,16828069
995972,
995973,16828069
995974,16827226
```

As you can see, most of my dataset is in the proper format but I have those commas on single id#'s also (my data is in form id#, connection#). How would I go about removing the commas on those single id#'s? I can't seem to figure it out just using a text editor. Any suggestions?

Edit: can I use some sort of regex expression to only remove it from those ids that have a specified length?

Edit2: Ok I figured it out using some regex, thanks for all the help!

Comment: "length" on a number? you mean magnitude? string length? What kind of trouble is the stray comma causing?

Answer (score 0):

In vi one would do something like

```
:%s/,$//
```

This means

***:*** (enter a line mode command)

***%*** (try the command on every line)

***s*** (substitute)

***,$*** (match a comma at the end of a line)

(empty replacement text)

Sometimes you need something like `/, *$/` do match a comma followed by 0 or more trailing spaces.  You can get vi on windows in various different ways; one way is to [install Cygwin.](http://www.cygwin.com/)

Answer (score 0):

You can select regular expression mode in `Notepad++` and do find and replace using the following regex `,$`. Leave the replace field blank.

Answer (score 0):

With the sed command:

```
sed 's/, *//' < FILE
```

or inplace (requires GNU sed):

```
sed -ie 's/, *//' FILE
```